# Why when clicking the button on the second time it's not loop over the array from the start?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have this button click method that I call it from `onCreate`:

```
public void addListenerOnButton()
    {

        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkipbutton);

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            byte[] response = null;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < ipaddresses.length; i++)

                        {

                                try
                                {
                                    response = Get(ipaddresses[i]);
                                    if (response == null)
                                    {
                                        text.post(new Runnable()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run()
                                            {
                                                counter++;
                                                text.setText("Connection Failed: " + ipaddresses[counter]);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    String err = e.toString();
                                }

                                if (response!=null)
                                {


                                    try
                                    {
                                        final String a = new String(response, "UTF-8");
                                        text.post(new Runnable()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run()
                                            {
                                                text.setText(a);
                                            }
                                        });

                                        iptouse = ipaddresses[i].substring(0, 26);
                                        connectedtoipsuccess = true;
                                        Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info(a);
                                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("encoding exception");
                                    }

                                    Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("test1");
                                    break;

                                }
                                else
                                {

                                }
                        }
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });

    }
```

For the testing I did that the string array `ipaddresses` will contain two items of ips that not exist on my server in fact my server is also not working at all and that's only for the test.

When I click the button first time it's making a loop over the array and in both cases it return that response is `null`.

But then when it finish I click again on the button this time I see that it's doing once `response = Get(ipaddresses[i]);` and `i = 0` and response is `null` but then instead getting inside the `if (response == null)` it's first doing the line `response = Get(ipaddresses[i]);` again now `i == 1` only then it's entering the `if (response == null)` and then inside I see that now the variable `counter = 2`.

Then my program crash. I guess it's crashing since `counter = 2` and the array size is also 2. But after the loop I did `counter = 0;` so why on the second time I click the button `counter = 2`?

Second why on the second time I click the button it's not getting inside to the `if (response == null)` when `i == 0`?

Comment: `text.setText("Connection Failed: " + ipaddresses[counter]);` should probably be  `text.setText("Connection Failed: " + ipaddresses[i]);`. (Or rather `... ipaddresses[ aFinalCopyOfI ] ...`

Comment: You don't reset `response` to `null` if `response = Get(ipaddresses[i]);` throws an exception.

Comment: Hanno this one of my problems if i will do text.setText("Connection Failed: " + ipaddresses[i]); i will get error since I should be final. But if i will declare I as global variable as final then it will not be the I in the FOR loop. And if in the FOR loop i will do something like: for (final int i =0;.... then i will get error on the i = 0 that's why i'm using the counter variable. Maybe there is solution for this but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Hanno where should i reset the response to null ? I'm checking twice once if it's null and once if it's not null. Maybe you could show me how the whole button code should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private int counter = 0;

public void addListenerOnButton()
    {

        btnClick = (Button) findViewById(R.id.checkipbutton);

        btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            byte[] response = null;
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {

                text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);

                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run()
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < ipaddresses.length; i++)
                          counter = i;
                        {

                                try
                                {
                                    response = Get(ipaddresses[counter]);
                                    if (response == null)
                                    {
                                        text.post(new Runnable()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run()
                                            {
                                                counter++;
                                                text.setText("Connection Failed: " + ipaddresses[counter]);
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception e)
                                {
                                    String err = e.toString();
                                }

                                if (response!=null)
                                {


                                    try
                                    {
                                        final String a = new String(response, "UTF-8");
                                        text.post(new Runnable()
                                        {
                                            @Override
                                            public void run()
                                            {
                                                text.setText(a);
                                            }
                                        });

                                        iptouse = ipaddresses[i].substring(0, 26);
                                        connectedtoipsuccess = true;
                                        Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info(a);
                                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                                    {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("encoding exception");
                                    }

                                    Logger.getLogger("MainActivity(inside thread)").info("test1");
                                    break;

                                }
                                else
                                {

                                }
                        }
                        counter = 0;
                    }
                });
                t.start();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: This one of my problems if i will do text.setText("Connection Failed: " + ipaddresses[i]); i will get error since I should be final. But if i will declare I as global variable as final then it will not be the I in the FOR loop. And if in the FOR loop i will do something like: for (final int i =0;.... then i will get error on the i = 0 that's why i'm using the counter variable. Maybe there is solution for this but i don't know how to solve it.

Comment: Please post the error you are getting when you use text.setText("Connection Failed: " + ipaddresses[i]);

Comment: Variabel 'i' is accessed from within inner class, needs to be declared final. But the 'i' is part of the for (int i = 0.... So i can't make it final.

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < ipaddresses.length; i++)
                          counter = i;
                        {` is definitely *not* what you want!

Comment: Try `for (int i = 0; i < ipaddresses.length; i++) { final int const_i = i; response = null; ...` and then use `const_i` in the inner class.